# Function in C to sum variables

Tags: c

I'm trying to use the following code but i'm not sure where the issue is, I'm trying to make a function that sums 2 variables and call it later on in the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void func(int sum) {
  int a;
  int b;
  int sum = a+b;
  printf("sum is %d", sum);
}



int main()
{
    printf("Enter a:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter b\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    return func(sum);

}
```

Comment: You need to define the problem.

Comment: You have to _pass_ `a`and `b` to the function and _return_ the sum. This kind of programming question is a bit too basic for this site, you have to gather some more knowledge first, e.g. with online tutorials or a good book

Comment: @JamesJenkins I wouldn't ask if I knew the problem, the program is just not building and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Void function means no return type. What you can do is change the return type of func as int and return the sum. Catch the return value in your main function and you can print that result.

Comment: You need t study the concept of "scope". Variables can be local or global. Also there are parameters and arguments.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer thank you! i didn't know that about the void function

Comment: @Ctx thanks, i'll make sure to do that

Comment: @EugeneSh.thanks a lot, i'll read about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in a and b to your sum function, and not declare them as local variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sum(int a, int b) {
    int sum = a+b;
    printf("sum is %d", sum);
}


int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter a:\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter b\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    sum(a,b);
}
```

Comment: When the function's name is `sum`, I would expect it to _return_ the sum, and not print it. Otherwise it should be called `printsum` or similar ,)

Comment: @Ctx I agree. But, that's not what the OP's function wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass '`a`' and '`b`' to the perticular function not '`sum`', since those two parameters are what's required by the function to complete it's task.

Second, you call the function without return, as

```
   ... 
    sum(a, b);
    Return 0;
```